# JQuery: How replace text AFTER a nested tag?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to figure out the jQuery statement to rename "apple" with "orange:"

```
<a id="alvin" href="http://www.camille.com"><ins class="xxx">Anna</ins>apple</a>
```

Can this be done easily?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I removed the `#` from the ID, since it is not a valid ID character.

Given that, try this:

**Live Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/u49wy/

```
var $contents = $('#alvin').contents();

$contents[$contents.length - 1].nodeValue = 'orange';
```

`.contents()` returns all the child nodes of the element, including text nodes.

The code then grabs the last <s>element</s> node (which is a text node) and updates its `nodeValue`, which is how you update the value of a text node.

- `.contents()` - http://api.jquery.com/contents

Answer (score 6):

patrick beat me to it, but my solution is a little more dynamic in that it would select the text anywhere, even if there were tags on either side:

```
$('#alvin').contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
})[0].nodeValue = "orange";
```

It does this by filtering the contents so that only text nodes remain, and changes the first `nodeValue` to "orange".

http://jsfiddle.net/ssRyB/

Answer (score 1):

`id="#alvin"` is not valid syntax, '#' is used as part of a selector for jQuery or in CSS.

For this very limited example, replace "apple" with "orange" I would actually simply read the `innerHTML` and rewrite it. I'm not even using jQuery for this.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var alvin = document.getElementById('alvin')
    alvin.innerHTML = alvin.innerHTML.replace('apple', 'orange');
}
```

I used no jQuery because jQuery does not have a clean way to select stray text nodes. So what if we wrapped any child text nodes in spans? We could do this:

```
$('#alvin').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).wrap('<span></span>').end();
```

In that way, we are left with the structure:

```
<a id="alvin" href="http://www.camille.com"><ins class="xxx">Anna</ins><span>apple</span></a>
```

Then we can use the `+` adjacent selector to get at it, like this -- `ins+span` means a `<span>` after an `<ins>`:

```
var elem = $('#alvin ins+span');
elem.text(elem.text().replace('apple', 'orange'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way (not very pretty though):

```
$("#alvin").html($("#alvin").html().replace(/apple$/,'orange'));
```

**Edit:** Added the $ at the end of apple. Thanks Patrick.

Comment: It actually won't work with the closing `a` tag, since it is not part of the content of `#alvin`. The `.html()` method will only return the inner HTML content. Not any part of the tag set matched by the selector. You could use an end of input indicator `$`, though. :)